# How to print all output at same time

Tags: java, string

I am giving one total number and that much string I am taking from input.

My Code is :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
         int tot = sc.nextInt();
         for(int i=0; i<r; i++){
             int L;
            String str = sc.next();  
            if(L == str.length()) {
              print(str);
          }  


        }
    }

private static void print(String str){
    System.out.println("String is "+ str);
}
```

In this code my string is printing just after I giving input.

```
OutPut : 3
"ABC"
String is ABC
"ABCD"
String is ABCD
"ABCDE"
String is ABCDE
```

But What I want is It take all input first and then print;

Ex :

```
OutPut : 3
"ABC"
"ABCD"
"ABCDE"

String is ABC
String is ABCD
String is ABCDE
```

Can anybody please explain and help me how to modify my string.

Note :  My Idea is put all everything into stack but again don't know who to print. I know My result is coming becasuse of for loop but not sure how to comeout from that

Comment: where is the print method??

Comment: use a `String[] str` array and add vlaues like this `str[i]=sc.next();`. after your loop call `print(str);` but change parameter of method to string array. then iterate over the array and print each value

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ I update my question

Comment: put your string builder or concatenate action in if statement ..

Answer (score 1):

save all your text in one global vairable

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
String str="";
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
         int tot = sc.nextInt();
         for(int i=0; i<r; i++){
            str += sc.next();

        }
 print(str);
    }

private static void print(String str){
    System.out.println("String is "+ str);
}
```

Comment: I cannot use print method outside the for loop because for each string I am checking one condition with respect to its length. I update my question. Can you please have a look again.

Comment: you didn't initialize L before the comparison, Sorry but i don't understand your point , what did you mean

Comment: you can use print where ever you want

Answer (score 1):

there is simple way to do it.

Use StringBuilder as follows in your code:

```
  ...
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
     for(int i=0; i<r; i++){
             String str = sc.next();
            sb.append(str);
     }
    return/print sb.toString();
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

1st thing: move the print method out of the for loop, you need to do that only once once the input is collected, then use a String object and append the inputs, maybe use a new-line char after each loop iteration.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int tot = sc.nextInt();
    String str = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < tot; i++) {
        str += "String is: ";
        str += sc.next();
        str += "\n";
    }
    print(str);
    sc.close();
}

private static void print(String str) {
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

Comment: I cannot use print method outside the for loop because for each string I am checking one condition with respect to its length. I update my question. Can you please have a look again.

Comment: what exactly the condition is ??

Answer (score 0):

> I cannot use print method outside the for loop because for each string
>   I am checking one condition with respect to its length. I update my
>   question. Can you please have a look again

since you have asked this i have updated [ΦXocę 웃 Пepeúpa ツ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/982161/%CE%A6xoc%C4%99-%EC%9B%83-%D0%9Fepe%C3%BApa-%E3%83%84) answer.
hope this may help you out..

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int tot = sc.nextInt();
    int counter = 0;//add a counter
    String str = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < tot; i++)
    {
        counter++;//increment for for each input
        str += "String is: ";
        str += sc.next();
        str += "\n";
        if(counter == tot)//if tot ia equal to total number of intake then print
        {
             print(str);
        }
    }
    sc.close();
}
private static void print(String str)
{
    System.out.println("String is "+ str);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Gokul Let me try your answer.